# How do I set the charts Y axis to be dynamic with maximum value set at 125?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a charts populated in asp.net C#. I have multiple charts and each can range from 0 - 125.

which look like this if I do not set the maximum which one of it, the chart maximum will go to 140 if my series range max is 125.:
[image]
[image]

Thus I would like to set the maximum of Y axis to 125 however not staticly setting it for all charts. which mean I would like to make it dynamic still like the second chart image with the maximum set as 125.

Please advice thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Maximum value in Series, you may have to change YValues[0] to the appropriate 
// index for your type of chart (so that it measures the top of your markers)
double maxValue = chart.Series[0].Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0])

// yAxisMax calculated as max value in series + 10 then rounded up to nearest 10
// but capped at 125 below. You could change this to perhaps 
// maxValue * 1.1 to always get a 10 % extra above, anything goes
double yAxisMax = Math.Ceiling((maxValue + 10) / 10) * 10;

if (yAxisMax > 125)
    yAxisMax = 125;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = yAxisMax;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
```